# Set the Page Title for pagination in angular js

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I have an Angular JS Ngtable Grid where I need to set the titles for each and every page in the pagination grid.

I have li elements with ng-repeat="page in pages" .

Can you let me know where i need to add the title so that I can get Page 0 ,page 1 etc as titles when hovered over.

[Pagination Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUXdO.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [edit] your question accordingly. Sharing *relevant* parts of your code for example might be helpful, besides listing what you've tried already to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add page in span tag

```html
<span ng-bind="'page '+page.number" class="ng-binding">1</span>
```

Comment: Hey sridhar, That did not work. I want to set the titles for the pages when hovered over on pages basically.